# How can I control the number of output files written from Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Using Spark streaming to read Json data from Kafka topic.
I use DataFrame to process the data, and later I wish to save the output to HDFS files.  The problem is that using:

```
df.write.save("append").format("text")
```

Yields many files some are large, and some are even 0 bytes.

Is there a way to control the number of output files?  Also, to avoid the "opposite" problem, is there a way to also limit the size of each file so a new file will be written to when the current reaches a certain size/num of rows?

Comment: There's `coalesce`/`repartition` for the first part and nothing clean and easy for the second. You should probably use the bash command `split` for that.

Comment: @philantrovert that's not true, since spark 2.2 you can use `maxRecordsPerFile`, e.g.  `df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)..`, see e.g. http://www.gatorsmile.io/anticipated-feature-in-spark-2-2-max-records-written-per-file/

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thanks a lot for this! I didn't know about this at all. This is extremely useful.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of the output files is equal to the number of partitions of the `Dataset` This means you can control it in a number of way, depending on the context:

- For `Datasets` with no wide dependencies you can control input using reader specific parameters
- For `Datasets` with wide dependencies you can control number of partitions with `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` parameter.
- Independent of the lineage you can `coalesce` or `repartition`.

> is there a way to also limit the size of each file so a new file will be written to when the current reaches a certain size/num of rows?

No. With built-in writers it is strictly 1:1 relationship.

Comment: since spark 2.2 you can use maxRecordsPerFile, e.g. df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000), see http://www.gatorsmile.io/anticipated-feature-in-spark-2-2-max-records-written-per-file/

Answer (score 3):

you can use size estimator :

```
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator
val size  = SizeEstimator.estimate(df)
```

an next you you can adapt the number of files according to the size of the dataframe with repatition or coalesce

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The SizeEstimator refers to rows?

Comment: It refers To the objet size in byte .