# How to control size of Parquet files in Glue?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

I'm loading a data set into a DynamicFrame, perform a transformation and then write it back to S3:

```
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = someDateFrame, 
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {
        "path": "s3://the-bucket/some-data-set"
    }, 
    format = "parquet"
)
```

The result is 12 Parquet files with an average size of about 3MB.

First of all, I don't get why Glue/Spark won't by default instead create a single file about 36MB large given that almost all consuming software (Presto/Athena, Spark) prefer a file size of about 100MB and not a pile of small files. If somebody has an insight here, I'd appreciate to hear about it.

But practically speaking I'm wondering if it is possible to make Glue/Spark produce a large file or at least larger files. Is that possible?

Comment: you can specify spark.sql.shuffle.partitions properly rather than using default 200. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701265/how-can-i-control-the-number-of-output-files-written-from-spark-dataframe/50701742

Answer (score 2):

Using coalesce(1) will deteriorate the performance of Glue in the long run. While, it may work for small files, it will take ridiculously long amounts of time for larger files.

coalesce(1) makes only 1 spark executor to write the file which without coalesce() would have used all the spark executors to write the file.

Also, using coalesce(1) will have bigger cost. 1 executor running for long run time will have bigger cost than all executors running for fraction of the time taken by 1 executor.

Coalesce(1) took 4 hrs 48 minutes to process 1GB of Parquet Snappy Compressed Data.

Coalesce(9) took 48 minutes for the same.

No Coalesce() did the same job in 25 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet. But you can set `accumulator_size` in `write_from_options`.

Check https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/master/awsglue/context.py for how to pass value.

Alternatively, you can use pyspark DF with 1 partition before write in order to make sure it writes to one file only.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format('parquet').save('s3://the-bucket/some-data-set')
```

Note that writing to 1 file will not take advantage of parallel writing and hence will increase time to write.

Comment: Setting `accumulator_size` has no effect in the output file size.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `repartition(1)` before writing the dynamic dataframe to S3. Refer [here](https://datanoon.com/blog/spark_repartition_coalesce/)  to understand why `coalesce(1)` is a bad choice for merging. It might also cause Out Of Memory(OOM) exceptions if a single node cannot hold all the data to be written.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get why Glue/Spark won't by default instead create a single file about 36MB large given that almost all consuming software (Presto/Athena, Spark) prefer a file size of about 100MB and not a pile of small files.

The number of the output files is directly linked to the number of partitions. Spark cannot assume a default size for output files as it is application depended. The only way you control the size of output files is to act on your partitions numbers.

> I'm wondering if it is possible to make Glue/Spark produce a large file or at least larger files. Is that possible?

Yes, it is possible but there is no rule of thumb. You have to try different settings according to your data.
If you are using AWS Glue API [1], you can control how to group small files into a single partition while you read data:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame = someDateFrame, 
connection_type = "s3", 
connection_options = {
    "path": "s3://the-bucket/some-data-set",
    "groupFiles": "inPartition", 
    "groupSize": "10485760" # 10485760 bytes (10 MB)
}
format = "parquet"
```

)

If your transformation code does not impact too much the data distribution (not filtering, not joining, etc), you should expect the output file to have almost the same size as the read in input (not considering compression rate)  In general, Spark transformations are pretty complex with joins, aggregates, filtering. This changes the data distribution and number of final partitions.

In this case, you should use either `coalesce()` or `repartition()` to control the number of partitions you expect.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-job-output-large-files/

Comment: `groupSize` won't have an effect, see [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-job-output-large-files):
"Note: The groupSize and groupFiles parameters are supported only in the following data formats: csv, ion, grokLog, json, and xml. This option is not supported for avro, parquet, and orc."